# SQLite3 on Android - Only basic commands works (like CREATE and INSERT) "advanced" commands (like ON CONFLICT - DO UPDATE) doesn't work

Tags: python, android, sqlite, kivy, android-sqlite

I am creating Kivy app and building it using buildozer for android.

App works well except some more "advanced" sql commands. Creating tables, simple editing, inserting all of it is fine. But for example here:

```
    connection = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_data (text_body text, id integer primary key )')

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO temp_data(text_body, id) VALUES (?, 1) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET text_body = text_body || (?)', (text_body, text_body))

    connection.commit()
```

Only first 'cursor.execute' is working, and after that the code just stops. App doesn't crash, it doesn't freeze it just stops executing next line of code.

I have tried many things, made sure that table is properly created, db have correct connection, I even tried to do connection commit and close after each cursor.

I don't understand why some commands works and others won't work on android (on my computer everything works properly).

Is it possible that sqlite3 on android doesn't know other "advanced" commands?

Can someone please point me in a right direction?

Comment: The `ON CONFLICT` clause was introduced in SQLite in version 3.24.0 Check your version.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!